# MapBox (swift) markers resize on zoom (How to disable? Change marker size)

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-markers, mapbox, marker

Here is my code for drawing a line on a map and placing a marker. My problem is that the marker gets bigger as you zoom out. Is it possible to set dimensions to the marker or disable resizing on zoom? (iOS MapBox SDK, Xcode 11, Swift 5)

```
func drawOnMap()
{
    let cord = checkForShortestDirection()
    if cord[0] != 123456789.987654321
    {
        let coordinates = greatCircle(xlat1: cord[0], xlong1: cord[1], xlat2: cord[2], xlong2: cord[3])
        polyline = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
        //if let annotations = map.annotations { map.removeAnnotations(annotations) } map.addAnnotation(polyline)
        if let source = map.style?.source(withIdentifier: "line") as? MGLShapeSource
        {
            source.shape = polyline
        }
        else
        {
            let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "line", features: [polyline], options: nil)
            let lineStyle = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "line-layer", source: source)
            let magenta = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#c73fba")
            lineStyle.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: magenta)
            lineStyle.lineWidth = NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'exponential', 1.5, %@)",
            [14: 2,
             18: 20])
            map.style?.addSource(source)
            map.style?.addLayer(lineStyle)

        }

        let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
        let pointCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: cord[0], longitude: cord[1])
        point.coordinate = pointCoordinates

        if let source = map.style?.source(withIdentifier: "marker-source") as? MGLShapeSource
        {
            source.shape = point
        }
        else
        {
            let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "marker-source", shape: point, options: nil)
            let shapeLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "marker-style", source: source)
            if let image = UIImage(named: "plane-icon") {
                map.style?.setImage(image, forName: "home-symbol")
            }
            shapeLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "home-symbol")

            map.style?.addSource(source)
            map.style?.addLayer(shapeLayer)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("DrawOnMap ERROR: \(cord[0])")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you simply add the annotation to the map with `addAnnotation` rather than as a shape it will not resize with zoom.

Comment: I changed the addLayer to addAnnotation(point) and now rather than my image it’s a simple pin image. Also it still gets bigger on zoom out